# argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable in django froms

Tags: django, django-forms

```
def clean(self):
      """ 
      Override the default clean method to check whether this course has been already inputted.
      """    
      cleaned_data = super(tbmstappraisalschedForm, self).clean()
      #appsched_id = str(self.cleaned_data.get('intAppSchedID'))
      depart_id = self.cleaned_data.get('intDeptID')
      fromdate = str(self.cleaned_data.get('sdtFromDate'))
      todate = str(self.cleaned_data.get('todate'))
      pk=self.instance.pk
      #if tbmstappraisalsched.objects.filter(intDeptID=depart_id).exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).exists():
      #qry = "SELECT intAppSchedID FROM tbMstAppraisalSched WHERE intDeptID ='"+depart_id+"' AND (('"+fromdate+"' BETWEEN  sdtFromDate AND  sdtToDate) OR ('"+todate+"' BETWEEN  sdtFromDate AND sdtToDate))"
      qry = """SELECT intAppSchedID FROM tbMstAppraisalSched WHERE intDeptID = '{}' AND (('{}' BETWEEN sdtFromDate AND sdtToDate) OR ('{}' BETWEEN sdtFromDate and sdtToDate))"""
      res = tbmstappraisalsched.objects.raw(qry.format(depart_id.pk, fromdate, todate))
      for re in res:
        if(re.intAppSchedID != pk):
            msg = "The slot for selected department and selected dates exists"
            raise ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data
```

if there are no rows return in query then it is raising a exception 
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
Thanks in advance

Comment: In what line? If it's in the `for` loop, what is the value of `res`?

Comment: @AugustoMen it is raising in for loop

Comment: why do you hace a `tbmstappraisalsched` class? why donot you use the django ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify you code with [django Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and [great than](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt) and [less than](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt):

There is no need to use raw or foorloop.

I don't know you model, so are you query right? (are my query right?)

```
def clean(self):
      """ 
      Override the default clean method to check whether this course has been already inputted.
      """    
      cleaned_data = super(tbmstappraisalschedForm, self).clean()
      #appsched_id = str(self.cleaned_data.get('intAppSchedID'))
      depart_id = self.cleaned_data.get('intDeptID')
      fromdate = str(self.cleaned_data.get('sdtFromDate'))
      todate = str(self.cleaned_data.get('todate'))
      pk=self.instance.pk
      #if 

      res = tbmstappraisalsched.objects.filter( 
          Q(sdtFromDate__lt=fromdate,sdtToDate__gt=fromdate) |  \
          Q(sdtFromDate__lt=todate,sdtToDate__gt=todate), ~Q(intAppSchedID=pk),
          intDeptID=depart_id.pk,
      )          

      if res.exists():
          msg = "The slot for selected department and selected dates exists"
          raise ValidationError(msg)
      else:
          return self.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only iterate over `res` if it's not `None`. Also, you need to return `cleaned_data` instead of `self.cleaned_data`

```
def clean(self):
    """ 
    Override the default clean method to check whether this course has
    been already inputted.
    """    
    cleaned_data = super(tbmstappraisalschedForm, self).clean()

    depart_id = self.cleaned_data.get('intDeptID')
    fromdate = str(self.cleaned_data.get('sdtFromDate'))
    todate = str(self.cleaned_data.get('todate'))
    pk = self.instance.pk

    qry = """SELECT intAppSchedID FROM tbMstAppraisalSched
          WHERE intDeptID = '{}' AND (('{}' BETWEEN sdtFromDate AND sdtToDate)
          OR ('{}' BETWEEN sdtFromDate and sdtToDate))"""
    res = tbmstappraisalsched.objects.raw(qry.format(depart_id.pk, fromdate,
        todate))

    if res:
        for re in res:
            if re.intAppSchedID != pk:
                msg = "The slot for selected department and selected dates exists"
                raise ValidationError(msg)

    return cleaned_data
```